# How to create a file containing TAB with cat?

Tags: linux, cat

I wanted to create a file in my bash script using cat containing a TAB Char. However I couldn't manage to get it working. Here my tests:

Using plain tab:

```
cat >file.txt <<END
    Text after plain tab.
END
```

Result:

```
Text after plain tab.
```

Using ^I:

```
cat >file.txt <<END
^IText after escaped I.
END
```

Result:

```
^IText after escaped I.
```

Using \033I:

```
cat >file.txt <<END
\033IText after another escaped I.
END
```

Result:

```
\033IText after another escaped I.
```

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: The [topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) at Stack Overflow is programming and this question seems to have very little to do with that. I think you'd get better, and more, responses in a more suitable Stack Exchange site like [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Try without the `<<END` and use `^D` to end the input.

Comment: @SamiLaine I probably forgot to mention that I want to use this in my mailserver installer script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three examples shown.  The first works (perhaps some detail was omitted).  The other two (a literal `"^I"` and a literal `"\033I"`) will not produce a tab because [`cat`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cat) does not *do* that.  It *does* provide an option (`-v`) for going the other way, making the nonprinting characters displayable.

As noted in another answer, the [`echo`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/echo) command can interpret some backslash sequences.  For example

```
echo "\tExample with tab" >file.txt
```

There are some differences between the varieties of `echo` used on Linux as a standalone program (from coreutils) versus that which is part of the shell (perhaps `bash` or `dash` or `zsh`).  The [POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html) is a good place to start.

Comment: I used this as my answer becuase it is better explained here. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use Echo and tab character \t as shown below:

```
[purnendu.maity@unix ~]$ echo  "Example with tab: \t text after tab" > file.txt
[purnendu.maity@unix ~]$ cat file.txt
Example with tab:        text after tab
```